# gstreamer or mediastreamer2

Tags: voip, gstreamer

I am writing a SIP VoIP client application and need to capture and render audio and video. I searched and found that there are 2 alternatives - mediastreamer2 and gstreamer. I would like to know which one would be better in your opinion and if there is any other alternative as well.

Handling of the rtp packets would be done by the VoIP Client. The media library should just provide means to capture and render audio and video frames.

Please suggest on relative pros and cons in terms of performance and portability etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

gstreamer comes with lots of audio and video sinks covering many platforms and apis. It also contains a whole rtp stack and high level elements for writing such an application.

Answer (score 0):

I was using mediastreamer2 for ivrworx project - simple and works fine